# Gitlab runner, docker registry and self-signed certs

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I've set up a Gitlab registry with self-signed certificate. After that I had to convince docker app to trust my CA, I did this by putting CA.crt into

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.gitlab.yourdomain:5000
```

But you have to convince docker executor and dind service in Gitlab Runner too, I've done this by passing cert through volumes in `config.toml`:

```
volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client", "path/to/cert/ca.crt:/etc/docker/registry.gitlab.yourdomain:5000/ca.crt"]
```

See the problem? Gitlab Runner uses old volume specification, so `:5000` part will break it. I know about existence of `pre_clone_script`, so that you can map your cert into some folder and then move it. But that will not solve the dind service problem - `pre_clone_script` will only be executed in 'main' container.

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, the answer was simple: why do you need to use `volume` only for file transfer? Just `volume` the directory, containing problematic folder with cert in it.